# Automate moving and renaming files

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, folders

I have files nested within multiple sub-folders. I want to move these files, one folder up the folder structure and rename the files as per its new parent folder. I will need this to be automated with a script.

### Example logic

1. Find **Root folder**
2. Get contents of **Subfolder** of **Subfolder** files.
3. Move files to its **Parent folder** (aka 'Attachments' folder)
4. Rename files to with its current **Parent folder** name.
5. Delete empty **Subfolder**
6. Loop above action of **Root folder** folders until complete.

### Renaming details

**Attachments** folder could one to many file of `.png` or `.jpg`. For example, **Attachments** folder could have `Apple.png` and `Dog-house.jpg`. If these files are moved and renamed, I'm expecting the file name to be something like this `MCP##-##### - abc.png` and `MCP##-##### - abc.jpg`.

If there is more then one file with the same file type, then the naming to be something like this `MCP##-##### - abc.png` and `MCP##-##### - abc (1).png`

### Example folder structure

[image]

### Desired Result

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm assuming this may require to Automate with a script but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the hierarchal folder structure always as shown in the pictures, e.g. `../Applications/MCP##-##### - abc.../Attachments/` and there is only one JPEG file in each the Attachments folder and only one Attachments folder in the e.g. `MCP##-##### - abc...` folders?

Comment: @user3439894 - The hierarchal folder structure remains the same throughout the Root folder (as displayed within the screenshots), however, the `Attachments` folder could contain one to many files and file types could be `.jpeg` or `.png`

Comment: What is, "folder could contain one to maybe files"? If there is more then one file, can they have the same extension but different base names? If they do, then the wanted naming convention will over write one more of the files! Please edit your question to contain all details!

Comment: For example, a `Attachments` folder could have `Apple.png` and `Dog-house.jpeg`. If these files are moved and renamed, I'm expecting the file name to be something like this `MCP##-##### - abc.png` and `MCP##-##### - abc.jpeg`. If there is more then one file with the same file type, then the naming to be something like this `MCP##-##### - abc.png` and `MCP##-##### - abc (1).png`.

Comment: Naming convention information in your last comment conflicts with Information shown in the Desired Results picture. Please edit and update your question with all proper and relevant information!

Comment: @user3439894 - Have updated the information above. Thanks :). Are you able to help?

Comment: I'm certain this question—pretty much exactly, or otherwise very closely—has been asked and answered many times in the past 12 months on Stack Exchange.  If you do a search, between Ask Different and StackOverflow, you will be able to find scripts for this.

Comment: @CJK I did find something similar but going 2 levels deep within subfolders and loop this process from the Root folder, I cannot find.

Comment: You can ignore my now deleted previous comment and I've rolled back to the first version as `rmdir` will not delete a non-empty directory and the added check was unnecessary. It would have been necessary if I had used e.g. `rm -rf "$d"` vs. `rmdir "$d"`. Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an *example* **Automator** *workflow* that achieves the stated goal of your question per its defined hierarchal folder structure.

**NOTE:** While the *example* `bash` *code* used in the **Run Shell Script** *action* completed successfully nonetheless, the onus is upon the user to ensure that proper backups exist before using it. I'd even suggest making a small sample copy of the target hierarchal folder structure to test with before running the *workflow* on the original target.

For the purpose of testing this *workflow*, the following hierarchal folder structure with its files was created:

```
$ tree ./Applications
./Applications
├── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br
│   └── Attachments
│       ├── barfoo.png
│       ├── filename.jpg
│       ├── filename.png
│       └── foobar.jpg
├── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac
│   └── Attachments
│       ├── barfoo.png
│       ├── filename.jpg
│       ├── filename.png
│       └── foobar.jpg
└── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve
    └── Attachments
        ├── barfoo.jpg
        ├── barfoo.png
        ├── filename.jpg
        ├── filename.png
        ├── foobar.jpg
        ├── namefile.jpg
        └── namefile.png

6 directories, 15 files
$
```

The results of the **Automator** *workflow* run on the target above:

```
$ tree ./Applications
./Applications
├── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br
│   ├── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br (1).jpg
│   ├── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br (1).png
│   ├── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br.jpg
│   └── MCP19-00633 - Sport and Play at Br.png
├── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac
│   ├── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac (1).jpg
│   ├── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac (1).png
│   ├── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac.jpg
│   └── MCP19-00753 - Active Nabiac.png
└── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve (1).jpg
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve (1).png
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve (2).jpg
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve (2).png
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve (3).jpg
    ├── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve.jpg
    └── MCP19-00824 - A Family Friendly Ve.png

3 directories, 15 files
$
```

The image below of the *example* **Automator** *workflow* contains the *actions* used and their particular settings used from their defaults. Be sure to match the settings shown in the image. In particular, the **Get Folder Contents** *action* has the **[√] Repeat for each subfolder found** checked, and the **Run Shell Script** *action* has **Pass input:** set to **as arguments**.

[image: Automator workflow Image]

***Example* `bash` *code*:**

```bash
for f in "$@"; do

    [[ -f $f ]] || continue

        ext="${f##*.}"
        move_to_dir="$(dirname "$(dirname "$f")")"
        filename="$(basename "$move_to_dir")"

        cd "$move_to_dir" || exit

        if [[ ! -e ${filename}.${ext} ]]; then
            mv "$f" "${filename}.${ext}"
        else
            n=1
            for i in "${filename}" *".${ext}"; do
                if [[ "${filename} (${n}).${ext}" == "$i" ]]; then
                    n=$(( n + 1 ))
                fi
            done
            mv "$f" "${filename} (${n}).${ext}"
        fi
done

for d in "$@"; do
    [[ -d $d ]] || continue
    [[ $(basename "$d") == Attachments ]] || continue
    rmdir "$d"
done
```

---

Note: The *example* `bash` *code* is just that and only contains minimal error handling, and was checked using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). However, it may not contain all appropriate needed/wanted error handling. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for and it worked! Amazed!

Comment: @Andrew C. Duarte, Glad I could help and sorry I did not have time to comment the _code_ as to explicitly what it was doing, but knowing that it would work was more important.